# Find m for $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^m})\,dx$ converges

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to find all the values of $m$ for which $f(x)$ converges for this function:
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^m}\right)\,dx$$

I tryed this:

\begin{align}
f(x)& =\int_0^{\pi/2} \left(\frac{1-cos(x)}{x^m}\right)\,\mathrm dx = 
\lim_{t \to 0}\int_t^{\pi/2}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^m}\,\mathrm dx \\[8pt]
& =\text{(l'hopital)}= -\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{mx^{m-1}}
=\text{(l'hopital)}= -\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\cos(x)}{m(m-1)x^{m-2}}
\end{align}

From here I can see that $f(x)$ converges for $m<3$

Is that right? maybe there is another way?

Comment: Just to make sure, you can't make L'Hopital in there, given that you don't know if that function has a 0/0 form.

Comment: **Hint:** $\dfrac{1-\cos2t}2=\sin^2t,~$ and $~\displaystyle\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac{\sin t}t=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mix things up: you have a limit in $t$, but you apply L'Hopital for a function of $x$, and you also forget the integration.

Start by noting that $\frac{1-\mathrm{cos}x}{x^2} \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$ when $x \rightarrow 0$ (use L'Hopital twice or Taylor series). Then, by the comparison test with limit, your integral will have the same nature as (i.e. will behave like) the integral $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{x^2}{x^m} \mathrm{d}x$, i.e. like $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{x^{m-2}} \mathrm{d}x$. This converges for $m-2<1$, i.e. $m<1$.

Answer (score 0):

For $0 \leqslant x \leqslant \pi/2$, we have $2x/\pi \leqslant \sin x \leqslant x$ and

$$\frac{8x^{2-m}}{4\pi^2} \leqslant \frac{1- \cos x}{x^m}=\frac{2\sin^2 (x/2)}{x^{m}} \leqslant \frac{2x^{2-m}}{4}.$$

Using the comparison test, the integral converges for $m < 3$ and diverges for $m \geqslant 3$.